# How to make changes to style.php

Tags: php, css

I am working from a Wordpress theme called Dynamix.

The site is located [here](http://azeverything.com/music)...

If you scroll down to the post with a comment, you'll see a comment bubble, with a solid black background. If you hover over it, you'll notice it turns red.

**In Chrome's debugger, I found this line of code...** (It's long, but it starts with this)

`#content ul li.socialinit, #content` **and it ends with this background tag...**

`background-color: #252525;` (in the debugger).

In style.php, which is **[here](http://azeverything.com/wp-content/themes/DynamiX/style.php)**, I found the code, but I have no idea how to change it.

Looks like this: `background-color:#<?php echo $linkcol; ?>;`

I don't want the black background. I want it to say `background: none;`, which should fix my issues.

**I'm lost on what to do here...**

Comment: did you try deleting that line?

Comment: It is an image. Look for the code in style.css line number 951.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the style without modifying the original code you can try add this to your style.css

```
.comment.yes {
    background: none !important;
}
```

This will add a new style for that class. The `!important` part tells the browser not to let another style over-ride that line.

Comment: Please explain why this will/should work - even though this is not WP-specific.

Comment: I placed that class at the end of my style sheet, and it didn't work. Thanks for trying though. And BTW - You are all way too strict on your Wordpress specific rules. I wouldn't be using this type of stylesheet on a traditional HTML developed site. I only find these kinds of issues with Wordpress (sounds pretty specific to me).

Comment: @webfrogs If you know where the original declaration is then try removing the class name `.comment.yes` from it. You can't delete the `background-color` line because it's also used for other elements.

Comment: I simply removed the line of code and it worked. I didn't realize that was something I could do. Works fine now.